# How do I change an order date?

Tags: orders, php-5.4

I missed putting some orders in at the end of 2014. I need to change the dates so it doesn't show ordered n 2015. How do I do this or is it possible?

Comment: show screen sot

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, although not via the admin panel.

You can change the `created_at` date in the following tables in your database:

- `sales_flat_order`
- `sales_flat_order_grid`

Remember to change the creation date of invoices as well, if you want to, in:

- `sales_flat_invoice`
- `sales_flat_invoice_grid`